# My azure website doesn't show up on search engines

Tags: asp.net, forms, azure, search, web

As the title says. I have an ASP.NET web application that I published to my azure account. I did a little SEO and it should show up somewhere on the search engines but it doesn't.

It doesn't even show up if I type in the address in the search field. It works fine when typing the URL in address field.

My azure subscription is "Pay-as-you-go".

Any tips or answers are appriciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer mainly pertains to Google.  How long have you waited?  It's my experience that it takes a few days to a week minimum to start showing up (if you're using Google sign up for their web master tools and when you submit your site you can see when it's indexed and what pages are indexed which is important because they may skip content they deem is duplicated elsewhere whether it is or not).  It's also my experience (using Azure) that sub domains on "azurewebsites.net" end up with poor SEO but if I have a full domain on my site it ranks much higher.

I also assumed that you submitted the site to the search engines, if you haven't site up for a web master account and do that (Bing and Google both have these).

- http://www.bing.com/toolbox/webmaster
- https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en

In Google you can also search specifically for your site to see what comes back which will indicate that others can get to your stuff (even if it's buried 100 pages deep in other searches):

site:[your site].azurewebsites.net

Comment: It did! Thank you again! :D @b.pell